# Using a NodeView+NodeStore to display hierarchical data

Tags: c#, mono, gtk#

I'd like a NodeView to display some hierarchical data, something like this:

```
Father Mother
====== ======
Jon    Ann
 +Sons
 +--Jon  20
 +--Dave 10
 +Daughters
 +--Ann  
Ron    Mary
Paul   Eve
 +Sons
 +--Bob  4
```

"Sons" and "Daughters" should not be shown if they are empty.
I have created three bussiness classes: Parents, Son and Daughter, and I'm creating TreeNode subclasses to display them.
I designed a Window with Monodevelop designer, and recreated the nodeView with code. The nodeview doesn't display anything at all, and I would like to know why. Here's the code, in a single file so anyone can test it:

```
using System;
using Gtk;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Family.Model
{
    public class Son {
        public string Name {get;set;}
        public string Age {get;set;}
        public Son(string n,string a) {
            Name=n;Age=a;
        }
    }
    public class Parents 
    {
        public string Father {get;set;}
        public string Mother {get;set;}
        public List<string> Daughters {get;set;}
        public Dictionary<string,Son> Sons {get;set;}
        public Parents() {
            Daughters=new List<string>();
            Sons=new Dictionary<string, Son>();         
        }
    }
}

namespace Family.View
{
    using Family.Model;
    [TreeNode (ListOnly=false)]
    public class ParentsNode:TreeNode
    {
        private Parents parents;
        public ParentsNode (Parents p):base()
        {
            this.parents=p;
            DaughtersRoot rootd=new DaughtersRoot();
            SonsRoot roots=new SonsRoot();
            if (p.Sons.Count>0) {
                this.AddChild (roots);
                p.Sons.Values.ToList ().ForEach (x=>roots.AddChild(new SonNode(x)));
            }
            if (p.Daughters.Count>0) {
                this.AddChild (rootd);
                p.Daughters.ForEach (x=>rootd.AddChild(new DaughterNode(x)));
            }
            OnChanged ();
        }
        [Gtk.TreeNodeValue(Column=0) ]
        public string Father {
            get { return parents.Father;} 
            set { parents.Father=value;OnChanged ();}
        }
        [Gtk.TreeNodeValue (Column=1)]
        public string Mother {
            get { return parents.Mother; }
            set { parents.Mother=value;OnChanged ();}
        }
    }
    [TreeNode(ListOnly=false)]
    public class DaughtersRoot:TreeNode
    {
        [Gtk.TreeNodeValue(Column=0) ]
        public string Label {
            get {return "Daughters"; }
        }
    }
    [TreeNode(ListOnly=false)]
    public class SonsRoot:TreeNode
    {
        [Gtk.TreeNodeValue(Column=0) ]
        public string Label {
            get {return "Sons"; }
        }
    }
    [TreeNode(ListOnly=false)]
    public class DaughterNode:TreeNode {
        private string mName;       
        public DaughterNode(string s):base() {
            this.Name=s;
        }
        [Gtk.TreeNodeValue(Column=0) ]
        public string Name {
            get {return mName;}
            set {mName=value;OnChanged ();}
        }
    }
    [TreeNode(ListOnly=false)]
    public class SonNode:TreeNode {
        private Son son;
        public SonNode(Son s):base() {
            this.son=s;
            OnChanged ();
        }
        [Gtk.TreeNodeValue(Column=0)]
        public string Name {
            get { return this.son.Name; }
            set {son.Name=value;OnChanged ();}
        }
        [Gtk.TreeNodeValue(Column=1)]
        public string Age {
            get { return this.son.Age; }
            set {son.Age=value;OnChanged ();}
        }
    }

    public class MainWindow: Gtk.Window
    {   
        private global::Gtk.ScrolledWindow GtkScrolledWindow;
        private global::Gtk.NodeView treeFamily;
        private NodeStore storeParents=new NodeStore(typeof(ParentsNode));
        protected virtual void Build ()
        {
            global::Stetic.Gui.Initialize (this);
            // Widget MainWindow
            this.Name = "MainWindow";
            this.Title = global::Mono.Unix.Catalog.GetString ("MainWindow");
            this.WindowPosition = ((global::Gtk.WindowPosition)(4));
            this.GtkScrolledWindow = new global::Gtk.ScrolledWindow ();
            this.GtkScrolledWindow.Name = "GtkScrolledWindow";
            this.GtkScrolledWindow.ShadowType = ((global::Gtk.ShadowType)(1));
            this.treeFamily = new global::Gtk.NodeView ();
            this.treeFamily.CanFocus = true;
            this.treeFamily.Name = "treeFamily";
            this.GtkScrolledWindow.Add (this.treeFamily);
            this.Add (this.GtkScrolledWindow);
            if ((this.Child != null)) {
                this.Child.ShowAll ();
            }
            this.DefaultWidth = 400;
            this.DefaultHeight = 300;
            this.Show ();
            this.DeleteEvent += new global::Gtk.DeleteEventHandler (this.OnDeleteEvent);
        }   
        public MainWindow (): base (Gtk.WindowType.Toplevel) {
            Build ();
            Parents p=new Parents();
            p.Father="Bob";
            p.Mother="Mary";
            storeParents.AddNode (new ParentsNode (p));
            p=new Parents();
            p.Father="Ron";
            p.Mother="Ann";
            p.Sons.Add ("David",new Son("David","20"));
            p.Sons.Add ("Matt",new Son("Matt","10"));
            p.Daughters.Add ("Elaine");
            p.Daughters.Add ("Kate");
            storeParents.AddNode (new ParentsNode(p));
            this.treeFamily=new NodeView(storeParents);
            Gtk.TreeViewColumn fatherColumn = new Gtk.TreeViewColumn 
                                            ("Father",new CellRendererText(),"text",0);
            Gtk.TreeViewColumn motherColumn = new Gtk.TreeViewColumn 
                                            ("Mother",new CellRendererText(),"text",1);
            treeFamily.AppendColumn (fatherColumn);
            treeFamily.AppendColumn (motherColumn);
            treeFamily.ShowAll ();

        }
        protected void OnDeleteEvent (object sender, DeleteEventArgs a) {
            Application.Quit ();
            a.RetVal = true;
        }
    }
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args) {
            Application.Init ();
            MainWindow win = new MainWindow ();
            win.Show ();
            Application.Run ();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Gtk model binding works quite different than other toolkits. That being said, here is what you need to know for starters:

There are several types of "controls" or widgets as they are called in GTK that can display matrix/list data:

- NodeView (easiest)
- TreeView

Now, AFAIC, NodeView only exists in GTK#, that is, the .Net bindings. TreeView is available in all other bindings and is part of the GTK+ Core. The difference is that somehow, NodeView is easier to use but more limited.

You'll want to use NodeView if you only need to display list data, that is, no hierarchical data (as you seem to need though)

If you need to display hierarchical data then you'll use a TreeView.

Whichever you use, you'll also have to set up what you need in that widget to display, your columns for example. The difference between a NodeView/TreeView cells in GTK and other basic toolkits is that a NodeView column for example can display other widgets inside its cell instead of just text, so you could have one column that has a cell that displays a progress bar, or a checkbox. The widgets that you use inside these cells are called CellRenderers and there are CellRendererText, CellRenderToggle, etc.

Now, these controls are "bound" to data by "stores", for example:

- NodeStore
- ListStore
- TreeStore

Which one you'll use depends on your needs again and the type of widget you are going to use, so if you only need to display simple data use NodeStore, if you need to display hierarchical data use a TreeStore. One powerful thing about these data stores is that you can store in them not only the data that is shown on the NodeView/TreeView widget but any other data that does not necessarily needs to be displayed, you can even store objects, for example, you could have a store with 4 columns of which 3 are shown on the widget and the fourth keeps an instance of the full object.

In [this](http://www.mono-project.com/GtkSharp_TreeView_Tutorial) link theres samples for each case I mentioned that you can try. I think that you should be using the "Tree" model to accomplish what you want and not the "Node".

GTK is a powerful toolkit but sometimes its hard to understand how it works. I hope this intro works for you.